# How to make a post request with unprintable characters in data (python)

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha, encode, burp

## The Problem

I'm trying to make a POST python request to a request that I got from Burp Suite.
The POST Request has an unprintable characters in the POST data (See the screenshots below)

[A screenshot from my Burp Suite Repeater showing almost every thing like the Request and the Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIkH3.png)

[The unprintable data in the POST data marked in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t27H.png)

## My attempts to solve

**First attempt**

First I copied the request from Burp Suite by the extension `Copy As Python-Requests` the extension gave me the request with an empty data and this is unusually happens

```
import requests

burp0_url = "https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LeWfFcdAAAAAMh9dXVRrPe77wiFF4-rZmN17WDr"
burp0_headers = {"Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\"", "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"", "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.5563.111 Safari/537.36", "Content-Type": "application/x-protobuffer", "Accept": "*/*", "Origin": "https://www.google.com", "X-Client-Data": "COD+ygE=", "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin", "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors", "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty", "Referer": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LeWfFcdAAAAAMh9dXVRrPe77wiFF4-rZmN17WDr&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWdvZ28ubmV0OjQ0Mw..&hl=ru&v=6MY32oPwFCn9SUKWt8czDsDw&size=invisible&cb=1vsq9vk97xqu", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"}
burp0_data = {}
requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, data=burp0_data)
```

So I created two variable `burpA_data` and `burpB_data`

In the first attempt I will use the `burpA_data` variable which has the original POST data

I copied the original data from the request manually and put it inside the `burpA_data`

I tried to send the POST request without replacing anything in the original data or headers that I copied from Burp Suite
so I got this error

```
raise UnicodeEncodeError(
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201a' in position 4534: Body ('‚') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

I also tried to use `encode('utf-8')`

`print(requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, data=burpA_data.encode('utf-8')).text)`

but I got an empty response not like the burp response

```
)]}'
["rresp",null,null,null,null,null,1]
```

**Second attempt**

I tried to replace the unprintable data with it's hexadecimal value in the variable `burpB_data` then send the request

But I got also an empty response

```
)]}'
["rresp",null,null,null,null,null,1]
```